# What is the difference in installing MongoDb Binaries and Building MongoDb form Source with SSL Support?

Tags: mongodb

When installing MongoDb for the **first time**, what is the **difference** in installing `MongoDb Binaries` and `Building MongoDb form Source with SSL Support`?

I want to use `Mongo` as my database for an app I'm building, so do I need to install both?

Comment: After looking up what SSL was (https://www.globalsign.eu/ssl-information-center/what-is-ssl.html), I suppose that one must install both to ensure a secure connection later when launching the app! Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: The MongoDB community edition binaries do not include SSL support (at present). If you want to run MongoDB with SSL then you either have to build the binaries yourself with SSL support (in which case you don't need the packaged binaries) or alternately sign up with MongoDB for a subscription that includes packaged SSL (this is a paid subscription).

Comment: It is also worth noting that the binary downloads provided by MongoDB must pass a full run of the server test suite before being published. You can also [run the tests](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/tutorial/test-the-mongodb-server/) if you build from source .. and definitely would want to for a custom build that you are deploying in a production environment. It's also worth reading the [MongoDB Security Guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) which has helpful information on risk management strategies and best practices.